# extjs4 tree child item did not show until click on 'sort' header button

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I callled root.appendChild() to add couple children to a treepanel root and called root.expand() to expand the tree but the child nodes did not show until I click on any of the the sort button on the header.  Is there any property I need to set to show the child node programmally?

Thanks for help.

The following is the code:

```
        tree.getRootNode().removeAll();

        var root = tree.setRootNode({
            PRTNUM:'root',
            id: 'treeRoot',
            leaf: false
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
            var rec = result.data[i];
            var node = root.appendChild({
                PRTNUM: rec.PRTNUM,
                DESC: rec.DESC,   
                icon: this.convertTypeToIcon(rec.TYPE),
                id: rec.PRTNUM,
                leaf: true

            });
        }


        root.expand();
```

Comment: is root visible in your config?

Comment: Yes the root shows correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: do you start with an empty root? Meaning no other children?

Comment: Yes.  removeAll() child node before appendChild() loop.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that adding the following lines after calling appendChild() fix thie 'tree grid did not expand until click on 'sort' column button.  Thanks.

```
        root.expandChildren(true);

        root.sort(function() {});
```

Comment: I am glad this works for you, but this just does not seem right. Have youtried root.expand instead of expandChildren ?

Comment: I just tried both root.expand() and root.expandChildren() are working.  The tree nodes are appended successfully but it just needs a 'sort' either by user's click or by program to make the sort operation to trigger some 'redraw' to really show all child nodes. Thanks and have good day.

Answer (score 2):

Since your root node originally had no children it was marked as a leaf. 
I found that the following works for parent nodes that are initially leaves and you have to add nodes programatically:

```
parentNode.set("leaf", false);  //must be set to work properly
parentNode.appendChild(newChild);
parentNode.expand();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I did specify the leaf: false when setRootNode() but it still not show.  By the way, I found if I remove the treegrid's store the node shows but no text any all (only shows the icons with both root and its children). If I put back the 'store' property the expand() did not woprk.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: something is messed up with the config of the root, store and possibly data. can you post the smallest complete set of of your code?

Comment: I figure out calling a sort after append all child node will fix this issue.  Thanks for your help.